# Runtime Error when added subview

Tags: swift, runtime, fatal-error, subview

I'm getting a runtime error when I'm adding a scroll view as a subview, I'm not really sure why.

**Code**

```
@IBOutlet var myScrollView : UIScrollView?

self.view.addSubview(myScrollView!)
```

**Logs**

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

You myScrollView is nil. Maybe you did not point the scroll view in your design (storyboard, xib) to this IBOulet. The IBOulet pattern does not use optional variable, and with a weak reference, like this.

@IBOutlet **weak** var yourTableView: UITableView!

The easiest way to create an IBOutlet and to connect it to you UI is to use the "Assistant Editor" (the button with 2 cycles in the attached image)

[image]

Comment: So when I have it connected it doesn't work. When I change it from an `IBOutlet` var to `let` and don't have it connected it throws the same error

Comment: Use "Assistant Editor", it helps you connect your UI to your Controller.